# Infinite series of a sequence to a power

Tags: sequences-and-series

This may seem silly but is there a relationship between $\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|\bigg)^n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|^n?$ Will one always provide an upper bound for the other and are there specific conditions for this to be the case?

Comment: $\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|\bigg)^n \geq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|^n$ if $n$ is  a positive integer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you direct me to a proof for this?

Comment: If $b_i=\frac {a_i} {\sum_k |a_k|}$ then $0 \leq b_i \leq 1$ which implies $\sum b_i^{n} \leq \sum_i b_i$. Can you finish?

Comment: Also works for any $n\geq 1$ (not necessarily integer).